# Creating a thread in Java which takes a parameter and returns a result of different type

Tags: java, multithreading

As the tile says. I need to creat a thread which takes in a parameter of Type A and returns results of Type B. I couldn't figure out how to do this with runnable and a few results suggested using Callable, but those were dealing with results/parameters of the same type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement that `Callable` needs to deal with same types.

As an example:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<TypeB> {
    private TypeA param;
    public MyCallable(TypeA a) {
        this.param = a;
    }

    public TypeB call() {
        TypeB val = convertAtoB(param);
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah there is actually the Callable interface only allows one type of return parameter, and in your example you didn't surpass that as the call method of TypeB still returns B

Comment: So in my case I would need to take in Type A and Return Type B like Ahmad said.

Comment: @rinaldo13531 No, I have no idea what Ahmad is talking about. I answered your question as you asked it. If you don't feel that this answers your question then please edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: So you have:  public class MyCallable implements Callable<TypeB> but I want public class MyCallable implements Callable<TypeA>. Is that possible.

Comment: @rinaldo13531 The generic parameter of `Callable` takes in the *return* type. You can implement `Callable<TypeA>` only if you want to *return* `TypeA`. You can also add your own generic parameter if you want to parametrize the input param, or use 2 generic parameters if you want to parametrize both.